# How to find most frequent pixels values of a set of RGB images, excluding black pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, statistics

I have a large set of also large images (5000,10000,3 channels, RGB) from a semantic segmentation process. I am trying to create a new image with the most "common" value for each pixel, the mode of each pixel for the complete set. Those images have some particularities. First of all, they have the same size, but sometimes contains black pixels that represent no information and must be excluded from the mode calculation. Merging together all image set, I will be able to define which pixel colour tuple (r,g,b) is the most common and store this information as a new image without black pixels.

I have tried using `scipy stats.mode` to analyse a list of `np.array` from the images, but this method does not count the `(0,0,0)` tuple as a `nan_policy='omit'`, so after the calculation, it returns a black image. (0,0,0) is the most frequent pixel colour after all.

I tried also replacing the `(0,0,0)` tuple by a `'nan'` value but the ram usage goes up really fast and is not efficient.

Could anyone give me a hint of some vectorised method to implement this stat calculation?

Thanks!

some sample images: [img1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8tpjqy5zwhjo5dg/reprojected65.jpg?dl=0)[img2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue57ewtmg59aq8j/reprojected66.jpg?dl=0)[img3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ycpqbgf0cllkx8/reprojected67.jpg?dl=0)[img4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6fe6za0gq0ck8e/reprojected68.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Can you change your title to include 'RGB' and 'except black pixels'?

Comment: ok! changing to match the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you stored mixed tuples and nan values in a numpy array. This is not very effficient, because that would be an object array that needs to handle memory allocation separately for each pixel.

It is better to convert the each RGB tuple to a (integer) floating-point value. A single-precision float can store integers up to `2**24-1` without loss of precision; that is just enough for storing 24-bit RGB values.

Here is how to do it with 5 images of 50x100 pixels.

```
from scipy.stats import mode as stats_mode

ny, nx = 50, 100
imgs = np.random.randint(255, size=(5, ny, nx, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
imgs[:3, ny//2, nx//2, :] = 0 # ignore thsee
imgs[3:, ny//2, nx//2, :] = [255, 255, 254] # find this

my = 10 # slice size - must divide ny
mode_img = np.zeros((ny, nx, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

flt_imgs = np.zeros((5, my, nx), dtype=np.float32)
for iy in range(0, ny, my):
    yslice = slice(iy, iy+my)

    flt_imgs[:] = imgs[:, yslice, :, 0]*(256*256)
    flt_imgs += imgs[:, yslice, :, 1]*256
    flt_imgs += imgs[:, yslice, :, 2]
    flt_imgs[flt_imgs == 0] = np.nan

    mode_result = stats_mode(flt_imgs, axis=0, nan_policy='omit')
    imode = mode_result.mode[0].astype(np.int32)
    mode_img[yslice, :, 0] = (imode >> 16) & 0xff
    mode_img[yslice, :, 1] = (imode >> 8) & 0xff
    mode_img[yslice, :, 2] = imode & 0xff
    
print(f'Found mode: {mode_img[ny//2, nx//2]}')
```

Output:

```
Found mode: [255 255 254]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, As I said in the post, I need a new image with the mode of each pixel, so I changed the code for `mode_result = stats_mode(flt_imgs, nan_policy='omit') imode = mode_result.mode[0]  print(imode.shape)` and then convert the 2D array to a 3D replacing the integers back. the stats.mode is slow, but it manage RAM better than my method. Thanks again

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to be more memory efficient for generating a mode image rather than a mode RGB value.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it works well, but I takes 1 hour to complete the process for 72 4000*8000 photos. Also, loading more photos, aproximately 130 into the 4D array is crushing my RAM (colab 25GB). I am usiging a set of tiles now, dividing the image set in 8 groups and running different notebooks.